# how do you write a Maven script that calls a Jar file after the code in the project is packaged?

Tags: java, maven

The idea is to run "mvn package", as usual, and after all the steps are done, a Jar utility should be called passing the filepath of the packaged code (a jar or a war file) as an argument.

The utility would be called as follows from the command line:

java -jar Utility.jar -filepath {path of the new jar/war file}

I want to integrate that final step to the build process. How do I modify the pom.xml file in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). you can bind an execution of it to the package phase (would run after the built-in bindings defined by the packaging) to run java (the executable) with the arguments "-jar Utility.jar -filepath ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${project.packaging}"
the result would look kinda like this:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run jar utility</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-jar</argument>
                                <argument>Utility.jar</argument>
                                <argument>-filepath</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

though this invocation would be platform specific. you could improve on this a bit and use "java" instead of "exec" (you'd need to provide the main class name in that Utility.jar)

if you describe what the utility you plan on using does there might be a more cross-platform way to do it (for example the [maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/))

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to run the exec-maven-plugin from what @radai suggested.  If you can do it this way instead, I recommend it.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!--I don't want my project's dependencies in the classpath-->
                <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
                <!--Just include the dependencies that this plugin needs.  IE: the Utility dependencies-->
                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                <executableDependency>
                    <groupId>com.utility</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Utility</artifactId>
                </executableDependency>
                <mainClass>com.utility.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                <!--You may be able to use a variable substitution for pathToJarFile.  Try it and see-->
                <commandlineArgs>-filepath pathToJarFile</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.utility</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Utility</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```